# Find the y-coordinate at intersection of two curves when x is known

Tags: r, plot, coordinates

### Background and Summary of Objective

I am trying to find the y-coordinate at the intersection of two plotted curves using R. I will provide complete details and sample data below, but in the hopes that this is a simple problem, I'll be more concise up front.

The cumulative frequencies of two curves(c1 and c2 for simplicity) are defined by the following function, where a and b are known coefficients:
f(x)=1/(1+exp(-(a+bx)))

Using the uniroot() function, I found "x" at the intersection of c1 and c2.

I had assumed that if x is known then determining y should be simple substitution: for example, if x = 10, y=1/(1+exp(-(a+b*10))) (again, a and b are known values); however, as will be shown below, this is not the case.

The objective of this post is to determine how to find y-coordinate.

### Details

This data replicates respondents' stated price at which they find the product's price to be too.cheap (i.e., they question its quality) and the price at which they feel the product is a bargain.

- The data will be cleaned before use to ensure that too.cheap is
  always less than the bargain price.
- The cumulative frequency for the
  bargain price will be inverted to become not.bargain.
- The intersection of bargain and too.cheap will represent the point at
  which an equal share of respondents feel the price is not a bargain
  and too.cheap --- the point of marginal cheapness ("pmc").

Getting to the point where I'm having a challenge will take a number of steps.

**Step 1: Generate some data**

```
# load libraries for all steps
library(car)
library(ggplot2)

# function that generates the data
so.create.test.dataset <- function(n, mean){

  step.to.bargain <- round(rnorm(n = n, 3, sd = 0.75), 2)
  price.too.cheap <- round(rnorm(n = n, mean = mean, sd = floor(mean * 100 / 4) / 100), 2)
  price.bargain <- price.too.cheap + step.to.bargain 

  df.temp <- cbind(price.too.cheap,
                 price.bargain)
  df.temp <- as.data.frame(df.temp)

  return(df.temp)
}
# create 389 "observations" where the too.cheap has a mean value of 10.50
# the function will also create a "bargain" price by 
#adding random values with a mean of 3.00 to the too.cheap price

so.test.df <- so.create.test.dataset(n = 389, mean = 10.50)
```

**Step 2: Create a data frame of cumulative frequencies**

```
so.get.count <- function(p.points, p.vector){
  cc.temp <- as.data.frame(table(p.vector))
  cc.merged <- merge(p.points, cc.temp, by.x = "price.point", by.y = "p.vector", all.x = T)
  cc.extracted <- cc.merged[,"Freq"]
  cc.extracted[is.na(cc.extracted)] <- 0
  return(cc.extracted)
}

so.get.df.price<-function(df){
  # creates cumulative frequencies for three variables 
  # using the price points provided by respondents

  # extract and sort all unique price points
  # Thanks to akrun for their help with this step
  price.point <- sort(unique(unlist(round(df, 2))))

  #create a new data frame to work with having a row for each price point
  dfp <- as.data.frame(price.point)

  # Create cumulative frequencies (as percentages) for each variable
  dfp$too.cheap.share <- 1 - (cumsum(so.get.count(dfp, df$price.too.cheap)) / nrow(df))
  dfp$bargain.share <- 1 - cumsum(so.get.count(dfp, df$price.bargain)) / nrow(df)
  dfp$not.bargain.share <- 1 - dfp$bargain.share# bargain inverted so curves will intersect

  return(dfp)  
} 

so.df.price <- so.get.df.price(so.test.df)
```

**Step 3: Estimate the curves for the cumulative frequencies**

```
# Too Cheap
so.l <- lm(logit(so.df.price$too.cheap.share,  percents = TRUE)~so.df.price$price.point)
so.cof.TCh <- coef(so.l)
so.temp.nls <- nls(too.cheap.share ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-(a + b * price.point))), start = list(a = so.cof.TCh[1], b = so.cof.TCh[2]), data = so.df.price, trace = TRUE)
so.df.price$Pr.TCh <- predict(so.temp.nls, so.df.price$price.point, lwd=2)

#Not Bargain
so.l <- lm(logit(not.bargain.share, percents = TRUE) ~ price.point, so.df.price)
so.cof.NBr <- coef(so.l)
so.temp.nls <- nls(not.bargain.share ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-(a + b * price.point))), start = list(a = so.cof.NBr[1], b = so.cof.Br[2]), data= so.df.price, trace=TRUE)
so.df.price$Pr.NBr <- predict(so.temp.nls, so.df.price$price.point, lwd=2)

# Thanks to John Fox & Sanford Weisberg - "An R Companion to Applied Regression, second edition"
```

At this point, we can plot and compare the "observed" cumulative frequencies against the estimated frequencies

```
ggplot(data = so.df.price, aes(x = price.point))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.TCh, colour = "Too Cheap"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.NBr, colour = "Not Bargain"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$too.cheap.share, colour = "too.cheap.share"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$not.bargain.share, colour = "not.bargain.share"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cummulative Frequency")
```

[image: Comparison of observations and estimates]

The estimate appears to fit the observations reasonably well.

**Step 4: Find the intersection point for the two estimate functions**

```
so.f <- function(x, a, b){
  # model for the curves
  1 / (1 + exp(-(a + b * x)))
} 
# note, this function may also be used in step 3 
#I was building as I went and I don't want to risk a transpositional error that breaks the example

so.pmc.x <- uniroot(function(x) so.f(x, so.cof.TCh[1], so.cof.TCh[2]) - so.f(x, so.cof.Br[1], so.cof.Br[2]), c(0, 50), tol = 0.01)$root
```

We may visually test the so.pmc.x by plotting it with the two estimates.  If it is correct, a vertical line for so.pmc.x should pass through the intersection of too.cheap and not.bargain.

```
ggplot(data = so.df.price, aes(x = price.point)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.TCh, colour = "Too Cheap")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.NBr, colour = "Not Bargain")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cumulative Frequency") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = so.pmc.x))
```

[image: too.cheap and not.bargain intersect at x = so.pmc.x]

...which it does.

**Step 5: Find y**

Here is where I get stumped, and I'm sure I'm overlooking something very basic.

If a curve is defined by f(x) = 1/(1+exp(-(a+bx))), and a, b and x are all known, then shouldn't y be the result of 1/(1+exp(-(a+bx))) for either estimate?

In this instance, it is not.

```
# We attempt to use the too.cheap estimate to find y
so.pmc.y <- so.f(so.pmc.x, so.cof.TCh[1], so.cof.TCh[2])

# In theory, y for not.bargain at price.point so.pmc.x should be the same
so.pmc.y2 <- so.f(so.pmc.x, so.cof.NBr[1], so.cof.NBr[2])
```

***EDIT:*** This is where the error occurs (see solution below).
a != so.cof.NBr[1] and b != so.cof.NBr[2], instead a and be should be defined as the coefficients from so.temp.nls (not so.l)

```
# Which they are
#> so.pmc.y
#(Intercept) 
# 0.02830516 
#> so.pmc.y2
#(Intercept) 
#  0.0283046
```

If we calculate the correct value for y, a horizontal line at yintercept = so.pmc.y, should pass through the intersection of too.cheap and not.bargain.

[image]

...which it obviously does not.

So how does one estimate y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, and as I suspected, it was a simple error.

My assumption that y = 1/(1+exp(-(a+bx))) is correct.

The issue is that I was using the wrong a, b coefficients.

My curve was defined using the coefficients in so.cof.NBr as defined by so.l.

```
#Not Bargain
so.l <- lm(logit(not.bargain.share, percents = TRUE) ~ price.point, so.df.price)
so.cof.NBr <- coef(so.l)
so.temp.nls <- nls(not.bargain.share ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-(a + b * price.point))), start = list(a = so.cof.NBr[1], b = so.cof.Br[2]), data= so.df.price, trace=TRUE)
so.df.price$Pr.NBr <- predict(so.temp.nls, so.df.price$price.point, lwd=2)
```

But the resulting curve is so.temp.nls, NOT so.l.

Therefore, once I find so.pmc.x I need to extract the correct coefficients from so.temp.nls and use those to find y.

```
# extract coefficients from so.temp.nls
so.co <- coef(so.temp.nls)

# find y
so.pmc.y <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(so.co[1] + so.co[2] * so.pmc.x)))

ggplot(data = so.df.price, aes(x = price.point))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.TCh, colour = "Too Cheap"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = so.df.price$Pr.NBr, colour = "Not Bargain"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cumulative Frequency")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = so.pmc.y))
```

Yielding the following...

[image: correct-y value]

which graphically depicts the correct answer.